# detectar cierre de sesión con firebase y cambiar valor de usuario en database

Tags: firebase

tengo el siguiente problema, cuando el usuario inicia sesión, en firestore en un documento, se almacena un valor "active: true", que significa que el usuario está logueado. Cuando el usuario cierra la ventana o el navegador, se cierra la navegación, pero necesito cambiar ese valor a "active: false".

Estoy usando vue y firebase.

Necesito sugerencias.

Saludos y gracias desde yá.

Answer (score 0):

Existe este evento que detecta cuando recargas o cerras la pagina, adentro del mismo yo pondria el codigo de firestore para mandar el active a false

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Donde pondría el código? despues del preventDefault() y antes del returnValue?